# How to deal with constructors?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a code that shows constructor overloading..

My First form Login.cs and the code is.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    this.Hide();
    EmpPanel f = new EmpPanel(textBox1.Text);
    f.Show(); 
}
```

Second Form is EmpPanel.cs i have 2 constructors--

```
public EmpPanel( string uid)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.id1 = uid;    
}

public EmpPanel()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.button1.Enabled = false;
    this.ControlBox = false;
}
```

Third form is have a button cancel when i click on it it again return to EmpPanel.cs..

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    EmpPanel ep = new EmpPanel();
    ep.Show();
}
```

Problem is that when i click on the button4 of thirdform then it initialize the Id of EmpPanel.Cs then record is not saved in the database with that id instead of it the id is saved as 0.
Why..

Comment: Because `button4` does this: `EmpPanel ep = new EmpPanel();` and the parameterless constructor doesn't set an ID. What are you expecting?

Comment: I want to redirect the form to EmpPanel.cs from Button4_click without initialize the id..How can we do this..@AntP

Comment: Initialization is something that always takes place and sets fields to there default value. For `int` that value is `0`. If you do not want that you could make the type of `this.id1` `int?`, then it will be initialized to `null`.

Comment: It sounds like you need to pass an instance of `EmpPanel` between forms but it's impossible to tell you what needs to change based on the posted code.

Comment: What you want a complete code.

Comment: Make possible changes regarding to meet my requirement..

Answer (score 0):

You can change the parameterless constructor to set the id according to your business logic.

But it seems your id1 field is string, so its default behaviour is expected to be String.Empty. Are you sure that id1 is integer?

You can invert your logic so that database deals with id generation by setting identity seed to yes for your database table that keeps EmpPanel related entries.

Or you can change the constructor like this:

```
public EmpPanel()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.button1.Enabled = false;
    this.ControlBox = false;

    this.id1 = GetMaxEmpPanelId();
}

private int GetMaxEmpPanelId()
{
    int maxId = 1000; //get max id from the related table and return it
    return maxId;
}
```

Comment: id is not auto-generated.We can explicitly assign it-Ex-Emp007

Comment: @Mayank So according to your id generation logic, you can create an id factory class and set the id by using that factory class on the parameterless constructor.

Comment: @Mayank ie the method above GetMaxEmpPanelId can return an id the way you want it to be.

Comment: I dont want an max id but this will provide max id for ex-100.but i have to search Emp007

Comment: @Mayank So you should change that behavior (ie generate id's like Emp007) according to your id logic. I don't know how you structure your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
EmpPanel ep = new EmpPanel();
ep.Show();
```

you should return to the same instance of EmPanel. You can do it like this

```
EmpPanel ep= (EmpPanel) GetOpenedForm<EmpPanel>();
if (ep== null)
{
    ep= new EmpPanel();
    ep.Show();
} 
else 
{
    ep.Select();
}
```

Where

```
public static Form GetOpenedForm<T>() where T: Form {
    foreach (Form openForm in Application.OpenForms) {
        if (openForm.GetType() == typeof(T)) {
            return openForm;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: It gives an error-The method or operation is not implemented..
        private EmpPanel GetOpenedForm<T1>()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

Comment: Is your EmpPanel inherited from From?

Comment: Sorry. GetOpenedForm is an extension method I have. I forgot. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I used the above code but nothing will happen..it doesn't create any error nor redirect to EmpPanel.cs

Comment: try adding a form.Focus(); it should work depends perhaps the version